# Query to delete the last three documents in a collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Consider my database collection is having 5 documents and I need to delete the last 3 documents. So what is the query in Mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  $sort: {
  _id: 1
  }
 },
{
  $limit: 2
},
 {
   $out: "collection"
 }
])
```

Explained:

1. Sort collection by inserted order
2. FIlter only the first 2 documents.
3. Store back the content to the original collection replacing the original.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fDz4FxIV5dN)